# Appcompat missing in sdk folder

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to use android v7 appcompat library as the (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#) shows

the problem is the folder "appcomapt" which has to be in here(/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/) is missing

I've checked the sdk manager
"Android Support Repository" and "Android Support Library" is already installed

Could anyone please teach me where the "appcompat" is?

thank you

Comment: For me it's in the directory you listed (exactly in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`).
Do you have `Android Support Library` properly installed in SDK Manager (in Extras section)?

Comment: Yes I've checked the Android Support Library properly installed  , but the v7 folder only contains "gridlayout" and "mediarouter", I can't figure out why

Comment: Can you try to delete it and install again?

Comment: I have the same problem on my Mac.  Removed and re-added the support library via the SDK manager.  No dice.

Comment: What did you delete in order to make it appear?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on OS X. I updated my Android SDK manager to the latest version, deleted and re-installed the support library, and then it worked.